# Why is my Set containing blank values? | Swift

Tags: swift

When `mySet` is initially created it appears to automatically present the an empty object example: `[{}]` this then creates an issue when appending other values to the set for example: `[{"myexample":"WO5","id":3},{}]` how can I start off `mySet` without `[{}]`?

**I am using the following struct that conforms to Codable to represent my data within a Set:**

```
struct Model : Codable, Hashable {
    var myexample: String?
    var id: Int?
}

var mySet = Set([Model()])
mySet.insert(Model(myexample: "Example4", id: 3))

do {
    let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(mySet)
    print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: that's what you asked `[Model()]`

Answer (score 1):

The issue there is that you are initializing your set with an empty instance of your `Model`. You need to change your set initialization to:

```
var mySet: Set<Model> = []
```